# Cleaning Sleep Cycle Phone App Data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Motive: Coding project to analyze data about my sleep. Would like to plot Sleep Quality against Time (years).

Unfortunately, the data downloaded (CSV in excel) from the app is not formatted properly. Here are the 1st two lines of data:

`0    2019-11-22 22:25:26;2019-11-23 09:17:42;79%;0%...`

`1    2019-11-23 23:42:43;2019-11-24 08:33:26;80%;0%...`

which is:

`index, start, end, sleep quality, etc...`

I am only interested in date and sleep quality. Here is what I did to separate the tags.

`for index in cleanDF.head():`

`x = index.split(";")`

From here, I get the output `['Start', 'End', 'Sleep Quality']`

Now, I want to extract the 'Start' and 'Sleep Quality' from each row. I'm stuck here.

Additional Code:

`dataFrame = pd.read_csv('sleepdata.csv')`

`cleanDF = dataFrame.dropna()`

Comment: what are the first 10 lines of your input file and what load command are you doing for your dataframe?

Comment: Try this, `cleanDF[0].str.split(';', expand=True)`

Comment: try `pd.read_csv('sleepdata.csv', sep=';')` and `pd.read_csv('sleepdata.csv', sep=';', usecols=[0,1,2,3])`

Comment: @ScottBoston Exactly what I needed; thanks. Any recommendations for Pandas tutorials?

Comment: @TedPetrou  Yes, I like  [DunderData](https://www.dunderdata.com/) He great pandas training materials.